# Replace buttons location

Tags: c#, winforms

l have problem with my c# winform project.

In my project I have a function that switches the location of buttons to their old location if they are in the same area.

private void myText_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

```
Point q = new Point(0, 0);
        Point q2 = new Point(0, 0);
        bool flag = false;
        int r = 0;
        foreach (Control p in this.Controls)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
            {
                if (flag)
                {
                    if (p.Location.X == locationx[i] && p.Location.Y == locationy[i])
                    {
                        oldx = e.X;
                        oldy = e.Y;
                        flag = true;
                        r = i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (Control p in this.Controls)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++)
            {
                if ((locationx[j] == p.Location.X) && (locationy[j] == p.Location.Y))
                {
                    Point arrr = new Point(oldx, oldy);
                    buttons[j].Location = arrr;
                    buttons[r].Location = new Point(locationx[j], locationy[j]);
                }
            }
        }
}
   The problem with this code is that if they are in the same area, the buttons do not switch their locations.  Instead they goes to the last button location.
```

If someone could help me that will help me alot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` statement always evaluates to true. This means that the final `j` loop will do this:

```
// last time round the i loop, i == counter-1
// and q == new Point(locationx[counter-1], locationy[counter-1])
for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++)
{
    Point q2 = new Point(locationx[j], locationy[j]);
    buttons[i].Location = q2;
    buttons[j].Location = q;
}
```

The net result of this is that every button's `Location` is set to `q`, which is

```
new Point(locationx[counter-1], locationy[counter-1])
```

---

Why does the `if` statement always evaluate to `true`. Well, first of all let's look at a couple of the `or` clauses in the `if` statement:

```
|| ((q.Y >= q2.Y) && (q.X <= q2.X))
|| ((q.Y >= q2.Y) && (q.X == q2.X))
```

This is equivalent to

```
|| ((q.Y >= q2.Y) && (q.X <= q2.X))
```

The line containing the `==` test has absolutely no impact on the final result of the condition. In fact all the lines containing `==` can be similarly treated. This leaves:

```
|| ((q.Y >= q2.Y) && (q.X <= q2.X))
|| ((q.Y >= q2.Y) && (q.X >= q2.X))
|| ((q.Y <= q2.Y) && (q.X >= q2.X))
|| ((q.Y <= q2.Y) && (q.X <= q2.X))
```

We can condense

```
|| ((q.Y >= q2.Y) && (q.X <= q2.X))
|| ((q.Y >= q2.Y) && (q.X >= q2.X))
```

into

```
|| ((q.Y >= q2.Y)
```

and similarly

```
|| ((q.Y <= q2.Y) && (q.X >= q2.X))
|| ((q.Y <= q2.Y) && (q.X <= q2.X))
```

is the same as

```
|| ((q.Y <= q2.Y)
```

Combine

```
|| ((q.Y >= q2.Y)
|| ((q.Y <= q2.Y)
```

and you can see that the `if` condition always evaluates to `true`.

Comment: when i use just this part || ((q.Y >= q2.Y)
|| ((q.Y <= q2.Y) its still takes some of the buttons the the last location /:

Comment: but i did understod why its always true so tnx :)

Comment: i didnt understod what can i do to solve the button problam how can i chack the button area with out tuch the ather buttons!

Comment: I don't know what your actual problem is. I just answered the question that you asked. Which was "why do all my buttons end up on the last location?"

Comment: david i trying to somting else maby you will know why its not working